# How do i export a csv file from access db using asp .net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

I have acess db where i perform a select query which communicates to the sql and pulls up the data and export it as a csv file using asp .net 2.0

Comment: There is no need to shout, it will likely only decrease your chances of getting answers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/23345-Export-datatable-CSV-C-net.aspx

you will have to pass your DataTable to the function with the filepath.

Enjoy coding!!!